# I can't cut a human without hair issue

Tags: modeling, modifiers, particles, hair

i made a human with the human generator and then, I want to cut it in half to see  some anatomical parts that i created. I used both a boolean or the bisect function and it works. But the hair of the human gets completly crazy and spreads all over the face, wich is obviously not what i want but rather something like a clear cut in the hair. I can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Could you show a few pics?

Comment: If your hair is a particle system, when you cut a mesh in half you end up doubling the number hairs on the half that is left?

Comment: By the cut you destroyed current hair distribution since those operations generates new topology ... You would have to create anew one. Anyway to cut hairs straight I would recommend to create a new mesh just for hair with hide emitter and "cut" hair by shader.

Comment: a crazy beard :D. But if i could at least delete the hair before the cut, it would be ok, even though i would have prefered to keep them. But i don't understand how its created. it seems to be part of the body.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can try "cut" a model with hair by material ... try this Shader using transparency to hide a part of object.

[image]

Mask is controlled by Empty object position and rotation to get more freedom ... or easier to animate :)

To controll all materials transparency setup from one place share these nodes in **Node Group**.

[image]

[image]

You can also create a volume inside a body by *Volumetric* shaders ...

[image]

[image]